# Keyboard above buttons

Tags: android

can you please explain me how can I make an EditText so that it with activated soft keyboard would be above my buttons?

Like here.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to play with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` or `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in the <activity> tag in Manifest?

Comment: @roman-samoylenko Sorry, it's not used in activity, this is going to be a part of layout that is added to WindowManager in a Service

Comment: This keyboard is application specific not system default one.